# How do you render form from views in template without model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a problem with my Django Code.I'm trying to render a form from views to template and i'm just seeing the submit button. I noticed that we can use forms dynamically by introducing it like this {{ form }}, but when I use it, I just see the "submit" button on the page(Sorry I don't know how to upload a local image here). I join my four files: views.py, home.html, forms.py and urls.py
    Thank you in advance

**home.html**

```
<form method="POST" novalidate action="/config">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <fieldset>
    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Home</legend>
    {{ form.as_p }} 
  </fieldset>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
def inputHome(request):
    form = InputHomeForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InputHomeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            mk = form.cleaned_data['mk']

            return HttpResponseRedirect('blog-config')
        else:
            form = InputHomeForm()

    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
class InputHomeForm(forms.Form):
    mk = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'special'}))
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', blog_views.home, name='blog-home'),
]
```

I don't have an error message so i don't have an idea of the problem.

Comment: What do you actually see on the page?

Comment: You are missing <form> tag in html.

Comment: I'm seeing only the "submit" button.

Comment: @VanessaHONFO "it is not working" is the most useless description of an issue. If you want help, you have to provide _exact_ and _relevant_ informations, cf [mcve].

Comment: Yes sorry, I'm discovering the platform. But I revised the text in my first post. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are missing form tag in html.
HTML should be,

```
<form method='post'>
{% csrf_token %}
  <fieldset>
    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Home</legend>
    {{ form.as_p }} 
  </fieldset>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hello. Sorry. I wrote the form tag, I couldn't add it in the code when I paste it. But I did it. So, it's not about that.

Comment: @VanessaHONFO if you don't provide __exact__ informations about your issue, trying to help you is just a waste of everyone's time. Did you _at least_ inspect the rendered HTML ???

Comment: Hello. I revised my post to describe the output (Sorry I don't see how to upload a local image to show you). How to inspect the rendered HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Slightly unrelated (cf Nishant's answer for the main issue), but here:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = InputHomeForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        mk = form.cleaned_data['mk']

        return HttpResponseRedirect('blog-config')
    else:
        form = InputHomeForm()
```

In the else clause, you're replacing the bound invalid form (which carries the validation errors) with an unbound form, so you'll never get the error messages. Just remove the whole else clause.

Comment: I removed it, but no changes. For information, on my page I just see the "submit" button. There's no fields.

Comment: @VanessaHONFO I didn't say it would solve your current issue - actually I very explicitely stated that it wouldn't -, just that you _also_ had (another) issue here.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thanks